# Error 500 while trying to upload an image using FilePond and Laravel Spatie

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, laravel-blade, filepond

I'm trying to create items that have a picture/avatar using a form and insert them into my database, so I decided to use Laravel Spatie with the MediaCollection, but as soon as i implemented the library, I'm getting an error 500 when I submit my form.... any idea why? And how am I supposed to create my database fields so when I create a new item with a picture I submit, the picture is submitted in a  "Picture" datatable and in my "item" datatable I have the foreign key "picture_id" referencing to the picture in the Picture datatable.

Item.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\HasMedia;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\InteractsWithMedia;

class Item extends Model implements HasMedia
{
    use HasFactory;
    use InteractsWithMedia;


    public function inventory_list()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(InventoryList::class);
    }

    public function work_ticket()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(WorkTicket::class);
    }

    public function picture()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Picture::class);
    }
}
```

ItemController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\InventoryList;
use App\Models\Item;
use App\Models\Picture;
use App\Models\TemporaryFile;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ItemController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $inventory_lists = InventoryList::all();
        $pictures = Picture::all();

        return view('add-item', ['inventory_lists' => $inventory_lists,
            'pictures' => $pictures]);
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $item = new Item;

        $item->name = $request->name;
        $item->state = $request->state;
        $item->observations = $request->observations;
        $item->list_id = $request->list_id;
        $item->picture_id = $request->picture_id;

        $temporaryFile = TemporaryFile::where('folder', $request->avatar)->first();
        if($temporaryFile){
            $item->addMedia(storage_path('app/public/avatars/tmp/' . $request->avatar . '/' . $temporaryFile->filename))
                ->toMediaCollection('avatars');
            rmdir('app/public/avatars/tmp/' . $request->avatar);
            $temporaryFile->delete();
        }

        $item->save();

        return redirect('add-item')->with('status', 'Item Form Data Has Been inserted');
    }
}
```

add-item.blade.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Créer un nouvel item</title>
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/filepond/dist/filepond.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container mt-4">
    @if(session('status'))
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            {{ session('status') }}
        </div>
    @endif
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header text-center font-weight-bold">
            Ajouter un nouvel item
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <form name="add-blog-post-form" id="add-blog-post-form" method="post" action="{{url('store-item')}}">
                @csrf
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Nom</label>
                    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" required="">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="state">État</label>
                    <input type="text" id="state" name="state" class="form-control" required="">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="observations">Observations</label>
                    <textarea name="observations" class="form-control" required=""></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    Liste d'inventaire
                    <select name="list_id" class="form-control select2-multiple">
                        <option value=""></option>
                        @foreach($inventory_lists as $inventory_list)
                            <option value="{{$inventory_list->id}}">
                                {{$inventory_list->name}}
                            </option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="avatar">Photo</label>
                    <input type="file" name="avatar" id="avatar">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    @section('scripts')
        <script>
            const inputElement = document.querySelector('input[id="avatar"]');
            const pond = FilePond.create( inputElement );
            FilePond.setOptions({
                server: {
                    url: '/upload',
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
                    }
                }

            });
        </script>
    @endsection
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/filepond/dist/filepond.js"></script>
@yield('scripts')
</body>
</html>
```

UploadController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\TemporaryFile;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UploadController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->hasFile('avatar')) {
            $file = $request->file('avatar');
            $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $folder = uniqid() . '-' .now()->timestamp;
            $file->storeAs('avatars/tmp/' . $folder, $filename);

            TemporaryFile::create([
                'folder' => $folder,
                'filename' => $filename
            ]);
            return $folder;
        }

        return '';
    }
}
```

2022_05_06_063218_create_temporary_files_table.php:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('temporary_files', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('folder');
            $table->string('filename');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('temporary_files');
    }
};
```

Thanks in advance

Edit:

I got this error right before getting my Error 500, then I simply refreshed my page and I never got the following error again, just an error 500.

> local.ERROR: Declaration of
> Spatie\MediaLibrary\MediaCollections\Models\Collections\MediaCollection::jsonSerialize()
> must be compatible with
> Illuminate\Support\Collection::jsonSerialize(): array
> {"exception":"[object]
> (Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError(code: 0):
> Declaration of
> Spatie\MediaLibrary\MediaCollections\Models\Collections\MediaCollection::jsonSerialize()
> must be compatible with
> Illuminate\Support\Collection::jsonSerialize(): array at
> /home/vagrant/code/vendor/spatie/laravel-medialibrary/src/MediaCollections/Models/Collections/MediaCollection.php:51)
> [stacktrace]
> #0 {main}

Comment: A `500` error is very generic. Have you look through the log files (Laravel and server) to see what they say?

Comment: How can I change the log files on Laravel if I may ask @Peppermintology . At least there's no new log appearing on the laravel.log file when I'm getting my error.

Comment: you are missing form tag attribute for input type file :-  enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: even when using FilePond @AmirKhan ?

Comment: You're uploading asynchronously with `store` property so no need for that attribute. FilePond uploads both the file metadata and file object under the same form field name, maybe that is causing an issue? In classic PHP you'd get the file with $_FILES and the metadata with $_POST

Comment: have u resolved the issue or not or need help